# R read in excel file with merged cells as column headers

Tags: r, excel

In biological assays we often have replicate measurements from the same molecule and then plot a dose response curve using the average of 2 or 3 replicates. I would like to read into R an excel file, where the column headers of replicates have been merged - text example below, and [link to example file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28738708/demo.xlsx). The read_excel function of the readxl package can read the file in but unmerges the header cells and replaces the empty cells with NAs.

```
conc          |   Sample1    |  Sample2  
-------------------------------------------
10            |  1.5 |  2.5  |  3   |  4
------------------------------------------- 
100           |  15  |  25   |  30  |  40
-------------------------------------------
1000          |  150 |  250  |  300 |  400
```

Is there a way of either preserving the merged cell layout in R or alternatively reading in the columns and automatically replicating/renumbering the headers like below?

```
conc          | Sample1.1 | Sample1.2 | Sample2.1 | Sample2.2  
--------------------------------------------------------------
10            |    1.5    |    2.5    |     3     |     4 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
100           |    15     |    25     |     30    |     40 
--------------------------------------------------------------
1000          |    150    |    250    |     300   |     400
```

Thanks.

Comment: R does not allow duplicate column names.

Comment: Can you dput your read-in data? And also don't have duplicated column names in your data since you will not be able to access both of them using the name.

Comment: It's probably simplest to just read the data in without the headers, and add them afterwards. That said, there are a _lot_ of Excel reader packages: readxl, XLConnect, xlsx, openxlsx, etc., so one of them probably has a parameter to handle this situation.

Comment: After reading your comments I've clarified the question. The column names don't need to be the same (and obviously can't be) as long as the reading in function passes the column names to the columns directly. I've written a function that takes the existing column names and replicates them but is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but it is possible to have a list column, such that multiple values are contained within a single cell. This might serve the same function as the "merged columns" in Excel. Here's an example, just to show what I mean:

```
library(data.table)
new <- data.table("V1" = c(1,2), "V2" = list(c(1,2,5),c(2,3)) )
```

Notice that column `V2` has 2 vectors within a list (each vector is even a unique length, and each one can be as long or short as you need). Now you can call all the values for a given cell:

```
> new$V2[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5
```

Or a specific replication:

```
> new$V2[[2]][2]
[1] 3
```

I don't know exactly what your spreadsheet looks like, and getting it from its current form into a "list column" form may be difficult depending on that. Hopefully this gives you some ideas though!